# How to get datacontext from stackpanel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have:

```
<StackPanel  DataContext="{Binding Path =MyContext}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path =Content}" x:Name="tbName" IsReadOnly="False">
    </TextBox>
    <CheckBox x:Name="cboxName" Content="Is null ?" Click="cboxName_Click" IsChecked="{Binding Path=THIS, Converter={StaticResource MyContextToBoolConverter}}">
     </CheckBox>
</StackPanel>

public class MyContextToBoolConverter: IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
         return (value!=null);
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
            return parameter;
     }
}
```

I just only want to get `DataContext` to checkbox from StackPanel.

Comment: Can you copy the sourcecode of viewmodel which you want to bind as DataContext.

Comment: Why? I just want check if object exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or try this -

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" DataContext="{Binding Path =MyContext}"> 
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path =Content}" x:Name="tbName" IsReadOnly="False" /> 
   <CheckBox x:Name="cboxName" Content="Is null ?" 
       Click="cboxName_Click" 
       IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=StackPanel, Path=DataContext, Converter={StaticResource MyContextToBoolConverter}}"> 
   </CheckBox> 
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should replace `THIS` with `.` or completely remove the `Path` from the `Binding`. This will create a binding directly to the `DataContext`.

```
IsChecked="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyContextToBoolConverter}}"
```